# Apache removes header with underscore

Tags: php, apache, http

We use a header with a "_" (underscore) symbol in it in our webservices, but we just migrated our application from apache 2.4.10 -> 2.4.46 and from php 5.5 -> 7.4, and now, the header containing an underscore is not even recognized in getallheaders(), and the app absolutely needs this header in the requests.

How to force apache (or php ?) to accept any header containing _ symbol ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds a bit surprising, that you would only get this issue now? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html: _"Translation of headers to environment variables is more strict than before to mitigate some possible cross-site-scripting attacks via header injection. Header names containing invalid characters (including underscores) are no longer converted to environment variables. [Environment Variables in Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/env.html) has some pointers on how to work around broken legacy clients which require such headers."_

Comment: please take a look here 
https://serverfault.com/questions/933628/apache-underscore-in-header-is-overwriten